# How to set and access environment variables (private api keys) from Firebase Cloud Functions inside an iOS app

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, google-cloud-functions

I use Firebase for my backend, Remote Notifications, and use Google Maps and Places APIs inside my iOS app. Everything works fine but I want to [hide my api credentials](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037?hl=en).

To send a Remote Notification I need the server key from Firebase and to access the Google Maps and Places APIs I need their API Credentials

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    static var fbServerKey = "someReallyLongFirebaseServerKey"

    override init() {
        super.init()

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("my_Places_API_Key") // places api credential key
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("my_Maps_API_Key") // maps api credential key

        GMSPlacesClient.openSourceLicenseInfo()
        GMSServices.openSourceLicenseInfo()
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)    
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    }
}
```

To send a push notification I access the `fbServerKey` from AppDelegate:

```
let fbServerKey = AppDelegate.fbServerKey // *** 1. the server key is accessed here and used below ***

var params = [String: Any]() // add keys and values to params

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

// *** 2. the server key is used HERE ***
request.setValue("key=\(fbServerKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in ...
```

I have my Firebase Rules in place but if you look at the above code the fbServerKey and maps/places API credentials are all in **plain text**.

To avoid that problem I switched to using CloudKit:

```
// these keys are all set prior to going live and won't be inside the user's applications
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore().set("someReallyLongFirebaseServerKey", forKey: "fbServerKey")
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore().set("my_Places_API_Key", forKey: "placesAPIKey")
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore().set("my_Maps_API_Key", forKey: "mapsAPIKey")
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore().synchronize()
```

To retrieve the keys:

```
static var fbServerKey = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore()string(forKey: "fbServerKey")

GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey(NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore()string(forKey: "placesAPIKey"))
GMSServices.provideAPIKey(NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore()string(forKey: "mapsAPIKey"))
```

**The problem here is if the user isn't connected to iCloud then they won't be able to access the keys.**

Now I'm in the process of switching to Firebase Cloud Functions. The thing is I'm not clear how to use it.

1- In terminal I `cd` to my Xcode project folder and run

```
// $ firebase init functions *** I initially used this command but DO NOT RUN THIS line >firebase init functions<. Read the first comment below from @DougStevenson for the reason to avoid it
$ npm install -g firebase-tools
$ npm install --save firebase-functions@latest
```

2- I choose the fb project I want to deploy the cloud functions to

3- I set the keys using the below which I'm lost at because I don't know what `someservice.key` is nor do I know what `someservice.id` is nor am i 100% sure where to find `my client id` (I'm assuming it's the `CLIENT_ID` from the `GoogleService-Info.plist`)

```
$ firebase functions:config:set someservice.key="THE API KEY" someservice.id="THE CLIENT ID
```

4- Inside the provided `functions/index.js` folder I add some code to set the code from step3

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions'); // already present
// don't know what to add here???
```

5- To deploy the code I run:

```
$ firebase deploy --only functions
```

6- Now that the code is in the cloud I can somehow call that code from within in my app to safely access the keys?

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    static var fbServerKey = somehow_Call_The_Firebase_GetFunction_For_This_Server_Key

    override init() {
        super.init()

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey(somehow_Call_The_Firebase_GetFunction_For_This_Places_Key) // places api credential key
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey(somehow_Call_The_Firebase_GetFunction_For_This_Maps_Key) // maps api credential key

        GMSPlacesClient.openSourceLicenseInfo()
        GMSServices.openSourceLicenseInfo()
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)    
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    }
}
```

**I need help with steps 3, 4, and 6**

Comment: I wouldn't run `firebase init` inside my xcode project.  I'd keep it in a separate location so that it doesn't possibly collide with the stuff xcode does.

Comment: ok thanks Doug, I'll remove that from my question. I didn't know that